# Force HTTP request to not cache

Tags: http, caching, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to force an HTTP request to refresh. I know I can append ?rnd=seconds_since_epoch to the URL, but the URL in question might have a query string already that I don't want to break. Is there a header I can set to force a refresh?

Edit:

Experimenting a little more: One of the pages I am testing on is stackoverflow.com. In the HTTP response it sets Expires to one minute from the request. The browser seems to be ignoring the "private, no-store, max-age=0" and Expires header that I am setting and caches the response for a minute. <s>I don't want to dig that deep into PyQt networking, so I am going to use the ?rnd=seconds method.</s>

Could this potentially break pages that see an unknown GET variable?

Edit 2:

I did dig a little deeper and it turns out that QNetworkRequest CacheLoadControl defaults override QWebSettings setObjectCacheCapacities(), setMaximumPagesInCache() and even clearMemoryCaches()!

The trick is to set the CacheLoadControl of the QNetworkRequest to 0, or AlwaysNetwork (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkrequest.html#CacheLoadControl-enum). The default is 1, PreferNetwork, which fetches from the cache if it's within the Expires header timestamp.

I'll leave this here to save a lot of headache to the next person.

Comment: You have the options to disable from web.config, Global.asax etc so why do you want to disable caching from header only?

Comment: If there is already query in the URL, you can append `&rnd=seconds_sine_epoch` to the query part. If there is not, query part will be `?rnd=seconds_sine_epoch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did dig a little deeper and it turns out that QNetworkRequest CacheLoadControl defaults override QWebSettings setObjectCacheCapacities(), setMaximumPagesInCache() and even clearMemoryCaches()!

The trick is to set the CacheLoadControl of the QNetworkRequest to 0, or AlwaysNetwork (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkrequest.html#CacheLoadControl-enum). The default is 1, PreferNetwork, which fetches from the cache if it's within the Expires header timestamp.

I'll leave this here to save a lot of headache to the next person.

Answer (score 5):

```
Cache-Control: private, no-store, max-age=0
```

Although caching is decided by the browser so you can't guarantee that headers will be effective, setting Cache-Control to private, no-store, max-age=0 seems to work quite well for me.

Also make sure you set the Expires header to the current date/time. This why the browser will see their existing content as expired on the next request.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the problem is with the cache being to aggressive and ignoring these headers. See edit above.

Comment: Fair enough, glad you got there in the end. :)